# Is this reponse vulnerable to xss?

Tags: xss, appsec, web

My application is returning  category parameter in json body as the following response..

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO PSA OUR"
Server: nginx
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 139
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Mon, 26 Jun 2017 15:47:55 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: bf-geo-country=EG; expires=Tue, 27 Jun 2017 15:47:55 GMT; path=/; do                                                                main=.myapp.com;
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=120; preload
X-Served-By: cache-hhn1524-HHN
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0    
Vary: Accept-Encoding

{
   "response" : "an error occurred",
   "campaign_monitor_errors" : [
      "no config for Newsz<htMl onload=prompt(22)/></html>"
   ]
}
```

Can this lead to Reflected XSS by MIME sniffing in IE or Chrome ?

Comment: what happens in IE or Chrome when you test it?

Comment: Chrome views response as TEXT , IE downloads it.

Comment: Are quotes escaped? This looks non-vulnerable to me. There is a potential risk of DOM XSS depending on what the client-side JavaScript does with the data.

Comment: Json always escape quotes
"   -->>  \"

Comment: @YasserGersy - In that case I think DOM XSS is the only risk. BTW, although rare, it's certainly possible that a JSON generator fails to escape quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that the parameter should be encoded regardless. As paj28 mentions in above comment, it depends what client side page does with the data.

The book, "[The Tangled Web](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/tangled/)" by Michal Zalewski has a chapter about content detection.  He says, "In the history of the web, nothing has proven to be as misguided as *content sniffing*."

He gives advice at the end of the chapter. Primary tip from this book and from other sources is to use the `X-Content-Options: nosniff` header to prevent the browser from sniffing the content and coming up with its own answers and ignoring your content-type header.

Your browser's reaction to the actual JavaScript in your example will depend on the browser version.
Note:

- text/javascript content type is deprecated. The official MIME type for JavaScript is application/javascript  (as of 2006)  http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329.txt